# Android GPS location problems

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gps

I have a problem with setting current location with GPS.
It works like it should(notification about finding location, then set it properly) on Android 5.0.1(Xiaomi Redmi Note 3)
But for example on Android 6.0 (Sony Xperia Z5 Compact) it doesn't work at all. No notification, GPS position set never. On Xperia I even don't have button on the right of map which is showed by line in `code(mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);)`

On Android 4.4.2(Gigabyte GsMart Roma R2plus) also no notification comes up, but I can see button of current location on right on top of screen. But still doesn't work like it should.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    } else {

    }

    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    emailicek = user.getEmail();
    emailicek = emailicek.replace(".", "");
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    if (latitude != 0) {
        if (longitude != 0) {
            mDatabase.child("userdata/" + email + "/latitude").setValue(latitude);
            mDatabase.child("userdata/" + email + "/longitude").setValue(longitude);
        }
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

    if (latitude != 0) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    } else {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you requested the right permissions in the Manifest? 
to get the last known location you'll need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

for network based location, or:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

for GPS based location.

By the way there are a lot of good reasons why you should consider moving to Play Services to get your location, I strongly suggest you to read this:

[Getting the Last Known Location - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have all these permissions :)